# check in while loop for only numbers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I´m new to python and wanted to know how I can check with a while loop if the list contains only numbers ... else: print("sorry only numbers allowed")

```
numbers = [34, 39, 110, 303, 889, 223, 982, 7676]

def getsSumVersionTwo(listOfStuff):
    sumNumbers = 0
    for x in listOfStuff:
        sumNumbers += x
        return sumNumbers
print(getsSumVersionTwo(numbers))
getsSumVersionTwo(numbers)
```

Comment: The `return` should be outside of the loop. Also, you can just use the bultin `sum` function.

Comment: @GilMatzov: don't change the code of a question poster. even bad code should be left as bad code. otherwise people who answer a question can't judge the skill of the question asker and in the worst case you make errors not reproducible. fixing grammar, typos, weird wording and so on in the text is fine of course

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I changed the "return statement" that the function will return the summary and made it print nicer. the base of what he asked I left the same. but I will think twice before I will change again

Comment: @GilMatzov I know it is tempting to fix those little details, but it doesn't always make sense ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming with "numbers" you mean integers, use this:

```
all(isinstance(n, int) for n in numbers)
```

As you can see in this example:

```
>>> numbers = [34, 39, 110, 303, 889, 223, 982, 7676]
>>> all(isinstance(n, int) for n in numbers)
True
```

Comment: You can also expand this to `float`s with the following: `all(isinstance(n, int) or isinstance(n, float) for n in numbers)`.

Comment: @ErickShepherd: Or even better: `all(isinstance(n, (int, float)) for n in numbers)`

Comment: @CristiFati I didn't even know `isinstance()` could take a tuple of `type`s! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [34, 39, 110, 303, 889, 223, 982, 7676]

for x in numbers:
    if not str(x).isdigit():
        print("sorry only numbers allowed")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getSum(l):
    try:
        res = 0
        for i in l:
            res += i
        return res
    except:
        print('Only numbers')
```

Or

```
def getSum(l):
    try:
        return sum(l)
    except:
        print('Only numbers')
```

Answer (score 1):

What type do you define as "numbers"? int, long
you can do this:

```
numbers = [34, 39, 110, 303, 889, 223, 982, 7676]
numbers_type = (long, int) # add more types like double float, complex
```

and then check:

```
if all(isinstance(n, numbers_type) for n in numbers):
       return sum
else:
     print("sorry only numbers allowed")
     raise ValueError("sorry only numbers allowed")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow all number types (int, float, etc....) you can check for every element in your list, if it is an instance of `Number` (since every number type in python inherits from `Number`).

```
from numbers import Number

def only_contains_numbers(collection):
    for n in collection:
        if not isinstance(n, Number):
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a single line solution:

```
a = any(type(i) not in(int,long) for i in numbers)
if a is True:
    print("sorry only numbers allowed")
```